# Writing a Parquet file from multiple Python processes using Dask

Tags: dask, parquet, fastparquet

Is that possible to write the same Parquet folder from different processes in Python?

I use `fastparquet`.

It seems to work but I m wondering how it is possible for the `_metadata` file to not have conflicts in case two processes write to it at the same it.

Also to make it works I had to use `ignore_divisions=True` which is not ideal to get fast performance later when you read the Parquet file right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dask consolidates the metadata from the separate processes, so that it only writes the `_metadata` file once the rest is complete, and this happens in a single thread.

If you were writing separate parquet files to a single folder using your own multiprocessing setup, each would typically write the single data file and no `_metadata` at all. You could either gather the pieces like Dask does, or consolidate the metadata from the data files after they were ready.

Comment: Thanks! How would you create the metadata file after having wrote all the data files?

Comment: Or maybe it's more efficient to create an empty dask dataframe and use map_fn to populate it? But then how I control the writing on disk?

Comment: There isn't a single function, but you would start with fastparquet.util.metadata_from_many